# How to terminate a thread safely? (with the usage of pointer) c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am currently learning multithreading in c++11 and I am confused with the way to terminate a thread safely.

In c++, I know the way to create threads and use thread.join() to safely ensure main() to wait for all threads to finish before quitting itself.

However, I found that some multithread codes implemented via pointers are able to run even without using thread.join().

```cpp
class Greating
{
public:

    Greating(const int& _i):i_(_i){}
    ~Greating(){}
    int i_;
    void say()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << i_ << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(){
    Greating greating1(1);
    Greating greating2(2);

    std::thread t1(&Greating::say, greating1);
    std::thread t2(&Greating::say, greating2);
    return 0;
}
```

The code shown above will absolutely report the error "terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)", because I did not use t1.join() and t2.join().

However, I found in some codes when they use the pointer to manage the thread, this does not become a problem, as shown below.

```cpp
class Greating
{
public:

    Greating(const int& _i):i_(_i){}
    ~Greating(){}
    int i_;
    void say()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << i_ << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(){
    Greating greating1(1);
    Greating greating2(2);

    std::thread* tt1 = new std::thread(&Greating::say, greating1);
    std::thread* tt2 = new std::thread(&Greating::say, greating2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello WorldHello World12
Hello World12
```

There is no error reported. This made me very confused.

So my question is:

1. Why when we use pointer to manage the thread, we could not use the function thread.join()?
2. How to correctly terminate a thread? (probably wait for the callable function to finish?)

Thanks very much!

Comment: The big switch to pointers had following effect: leaking thread objects. Otherwise, the thread objects would be destroyed without join or detach. So it makes sense only the first case reports that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating objects with dynamic allocation, you have to deallocate the memory with `operator delete` so it calls appropriate destructor.

In the first example, two `std::thread` objects are created. At the end of `main` function, the destructor `std::thread::~thread` is called. Since the threads are not joined, the destructor reports an error.

On the other hand, in the second example, you called `operator new` so you create objects with dynamic allocation. But, you didn't call `operator delete`, so the destructor is not called. That is, the program didn't check whether the threads are joined.

Therefore, the only way to correctly terminate a thread is to call `std::thread::join`. If you want to use pointers, you have to do as following:

```cpp
std::thread *th = new std::thread(foo);
...
th->join();
delete th;
```